# Javascript: Communication beetween browser tab on same top domain

Tags: javascript

I have two website, eg.:

- foo.example.com
- bar.example.com

I want send some message between those site if there are opened in different tabs.

There are different possible ways:

- Postmessage
- SharedWorker
- localStorage

But each one require same origin or access to window.opener...

There are a solution browser side for communicate between tabs if the top domain is the same?

Comment: It is not possible! You need an server between which handling the messages between the websites.

Comment: You forgot *WebSocket*, but you need a common end point that enables that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this only in the frontend. You need a server (backend) where booth tabs talks with. So tab 1 can send something to the server and tab 2 get it from the server.
Everything else would be a big security issue!